# How can I request an unknown number of fields from my python code in App Engine?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have an HTML page in which the user may add any number of rows to a table, and I would like to request those elements in my code to use them in some calculation. Right now, if I know the "name" attribute of the field I can get it like this:

```python
class MyHandler(handler):
    def get(self):
        #Render the page.
    def post(self):
        my_variable = self.request.get('name')
        #So my_variable is equal to what the user entered.
```

The problem is that I don't know in advance how many fields there will be, as the user may add "n" rows to the table. It would be best if I could grab each column as a list. The HTML code may look like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a.1</td>
    <td>b.1</td>
    <td>c.1</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- More rows -->
</table>
```

Edit:
I made a little example in jsbin of how it may work:
http://jsbin.com/cejijag/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This isn't really very clear. How is the user adding fields here? Maybe you should show the input form.

Comment: It is just a table with a button that adds a row to it using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just adding multiple values to the same `name` field, you can get all the data for that field as a list via `self.request.getall('name')`.

Comment: I imagine that if I will have a name for each row of the table (not column), so wouldn't that mean I would need multiple .get_all() statements?

Comment: Which is why I asked how you were adding the fields. Why would you have a name for each row?

Comment: I don't know, I'm still learning this. If I don't label each row, how can I get the values without losing track of what is what? If there is a better way to do it, can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.request.params`, like this:

```
for param_name, param_value in self.request.params.items():
    print '{0} = {1}'.format(param_name, param_value)
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit how it would work?  It would be great if there was a way to capture a whole column as a list (see the example in the edit).

Comment: If you want to retrieve data as an array, use self.request.getall('name'), as Daniel says in his answer. Really, you just need to experiment with these 2 methods and see what works for you. That's the best way to learn imho

Comment: I am a bit confused about this, but I'll keep trying with his answer, thanks.

Comment: Try this. In your table, I presume you have text fields? For each column, make the "name" param the same value. So for all text fields in your A column, give the text field a name of "field_a", or whatever. Then, in your python script, use self.request.getall('field_a'), which will return a list of all text fields which have the name 'field_a'. Then do whatever you need with the list.

Comment: Great. Then mark the other answer as the correct one, as that's what ended up working for you!!!!